# How long should I let a tea with lemongrass steep?

Tags: temperature, cooking-time, tea

Every time I have a tea with lemongrass in it the tea ends up with a really strong and rather terrible aftertaste. I drink several different types of tea, and am pretty sure that I am letting the lemongrass steep for too long. What is the optimal time to let lemon grass steep? I typically start with my water at 100 degrees Celsius.

Comment: Having no experience with the stuff myself, I'd say start at 3 minutes and work your way up from there. If it's too much at 3 minutes go down. Experiment, after all it's your taste buds that matter. Also, you could try [cold infusion](http://www.curiouscook.com/site/2011/07/iced-coffee-and-tea-not-taking-the-heat-ny-times.html), where you leave the lemongrass for a long time (maybe 24 hours) in cold water.

Comment: Are you using fresh lemongrass or dried? Is the lemongrass the only thing going into your tea, or are you combining it with some other herb or tea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An0r4k,

I assume that you're making a cup of black (?) tea and steeping some lemongrass in it. If so, perhaps you should make the black tea very weak as its tannins might be amplifying the (pleasant) slight bitterness of the lemongrass to distasteful levels.

Alternatively, if you are steeping the lemongrass in hot water, try removing the outer layers of the lemongrass stalk. If they are old or tough, this can increase the bitterness of the drink.

In any case, check that there isn't any dirt trapped between the layers of the lemongrass.

Some recipies call for putting the lemongrass into water, bringing it to a boil and then letting it simmer for 10-15 minutes. I haven't tried this. Even if it does produce a smoother taste, then the boiling might well degradge any health-giving nutrients from the lemongrass.

Comment: Thanks, typically I make it in a ginger and lemongrass mixture. I'll keep this in mind.